# In influxdb, how to use top after groupby then use the result for where

Tags: sql, group-by, influxdb

For example:
There are 3 students, they have a few (each student can have different number of course) courses to test, now need to:

1.Group students by their average courses score.

2.Find the top 1 student with above Rank then list the student's all courses with score

Jack course1:70 course2:100

Min course1:80

May course1:60 course2:40 course3:100

For quiz 1, I did like:

```
SELECT mean(score) FROM table GROUP BY student
```

It's done.

For quiz 2, I can first get top1 student by:

```
SELECT top(mean, 1) FROM

(    
SELECT mean(score) FROM table GROUP BY student    
)
```

but this will remove the student key, how can I do like:

```
SELECT student, score FROM    
(    
SELECT top(mean, 1), st 
FROM    
(    
SELECT mean(score),student as st FROM table GROUP BY student    
)   
) WHERE student=st
```

As I can see, the student cannot be kept in the first SELECT because "mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries" error.

Thanks